# Using the c# sdk to create a facebook game application

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

Okay. I've just finished my first year at University studying games programming and i have the ambition, drive and idea to develop a Facebook game application using the C# SDK.

I'm not here to ask for a step by step guide for this i just need and hope someone is kind enough to help me fill in some blanks.

After writing a full GDD for my game i started putting together a UML document on the game flow and it appears I've ran into some points that i cannot envisage how to over come.

Here is the question.

The game i intent to develop will save game data and restore it with each use of the application. What i need to know is where this information is stored and how i would access this.

Can anyone please enlighten me?

(Thanks in advance)

Answer (score 0):

What kind of game do you want to develop?

To avoid later problems with scaling i would use either Azure Storage or SQL Azure.

http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/sqlazure/

http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/storage/